# How to fit a GARCH model using F#?

Tags: f#, statistics

I looked at Microsoft Solver Foundation, but, honestly, it seems that it works better with C# than with F#
Is there some library for F#?

The samples for F# of Solver Foundation includes a wrapper for F#, which is nice but incomplete; for example, you can't apply `log` to a Decision, unless you manually extend the wrapper.

It is my understanding that the R libraries do not allow you to use indicador funcions in your GARCH models, for example, it doesn't allow you to treat different the data that comes from mondays.

Comment: I've used the R type provider for F# to fit time series before (although not GARCH), as it enables you to use any of R's simple fitting libraries. You could try exploring that route? http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/

Comment: I had to laugh when I saw this post because 'garch-' is the stem of some dirty words in Argentinian Spanish… :)

Comment: So... What's wrong with extending the wrapper?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I also tried using the library with C# and it wasn't that bad. Considering that I might make mistakes when extending the wrapper (I'm new with the library, so there is a high chance that I commit mistakes), it seems that using C# is more cost efective. Having said that, if you only need what is provided by the wrapper, it is pretty neat.

Comment: @Pash101 I checked one R library and it didn't allowed the flexibility that I was lookin for. I edited my question and explained it better.